# Custon Razor HtmlHelper conflicts with namespace at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created a custom `WebViewPage`. That allows me to add a custom helper to the use in my Razor views:

```
public abstract class CompanyNameWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public override void InitHelpers()
    {
        base.InitHelpers();
        CompanyName = new CompanyNameHtmlHelper<TModel>(this.Html);
    }

    public CompanyNameHtmlHelper<TModel> CompanyName { get; protected set; }
}
```

Using it in my Razor as such:

```
@CompanyName.Theme.Image("logo.png")
```

The problem is that `CompanyName` is both the name I really want to use for the HTML helper and the namespace our code goes in. So, in visual studio `@CompanyName.Theme.etc` resolves to my `CompanyNameHtmlHelper`.

However, at runtime I get the error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Theme' does not exist in the namespace 'CompanyName' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

From which it is obvious that `CompanyName` is now resolving to the namespace instead of the HtmlHelper.

Why does this happen? Why does Visual Studio allow me to do this when it's going to give me a runtime error? Are there any work arounds? It's really annoying to have to come up with some convoluted name instead of just the name of my company.